# Calling a function on screen refresh

Tags: c, refresh, screen

Kind of like this unanswered question: [Calling a method on screen refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981003/calling-a-method-on-screen-refresh)

Instead of dealing specifically with C#, though, I want to know how one could possibly do this through *any* API exposed through C. I'm using GTK+ via D, but I'm okay with adding hooks to any other library exposing a C API.

Before anyone starts yelling at me about the applicability of this: I'm trying to perform visual stimulation using an LCD screen rather than a wall of LEDs attached to some crystal oscillator (it's easier to use readily available 59.94 Hz screens than constructing LED walls). To even begin to approach the flexibility provided by analog circuitry, though... *no frame should be skipped*, ***EVER*** (or at least only very very rarely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New versions of GTK (3.8 onwards) introduced a `GdkFrameClock` API, for syncing drawing (of animations, etc) to vertical blanks. From a cursory look, it seems like it might be what you're after.

Docs: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-GdkFrameClock.html

Comment: This appears to be just what I was looking for (D's GTK port also supports 3.8, so this is doubly kewl)! Thanks!